# How to intersect two rasters in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I have two raster layers with different resolutions that I want to join [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5sw4.png). One has higher resolution (transparent yellow) and the other raster has lower resolution but bigger extent (whole earth) and has information about different classes (drawn in different colors here). The resulting raster should have the higher resolution and extent of the raster drawn in yellow here but should be joined with the other raster, e.g. containing the information of what class it was laying within.

Really appreciate any help!
Cheers

Comment: This does not seem to be a coding question and thus not appropriate for this site. You may have more luck on https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try my luck there also.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use mosaic rasters. Use Mosaic To New Raster tool.
But before rasters should have equal standart.
Use Resample tool for change resolution.

And your raster value system should be same scale. Arcmap will mosaic them anyway. But it can be wrong.
For example LST rasters. Suppose the raster is on a scale of 1 Fahrenheit and the raster is on a scale of 2 degrees Celsius.
In this case, even if the tools run and generate a new raster layer, the values will be incorrect.

I hope this answer was helpful.
Good luck with.